# How to solve ODE at a single time step?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the classical forced damped spring mass equation with a sinusoidal varying force.

$$\ddot{x}+2\xi\omega_0\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x = F_0\sin(\omega t)$$

The initial conditions at $t=0$ are $x(0)=\dot{x}(0)=0$.
It is relatively easy to solve this equation numerically, for example by using odeint from the SciPy python module. However, how do I solve this equation when the $F_0$ also changes over time? Think of it like this, a person is the providing the sinusoidal varying force to the mass, but a person is hardly ever able to provide the exact same amplitude $F_0$. Rather, it fluctuates in a seemingly random way.

Ideally, I would like to know how to solve the equation at every single time step where $F_0$ is known and initial conditions are taken from the previous time step. Some psuedo code is appreciated as well.

Comment: You mean how to take a fixed-step method stepper and build a time loop around it? Or how to make an interpolating function around the time series of the $F_0$ values and feed that into the rhs function for odeint? Or how to simulate a randomly changing $F_0$ via some SDE?

Comment: I mean given the initial conditions and $F_0$ calculate $x$ for time step 0. Then, update the calculate the new value of $F_0$, which depends on $x$, and then repeating the procedure. Only, now the initial conditions are based on the result of the first time step.

Comment: You mean like, after initialization, loop over `t_part,x_part=integrate(t0,x0,F0=F_amp(x0),t0+dt); t0,x0 = t_part[-1],x_part[-1]; t_sol.extend(t_part[:-1]); x_sol.extend(x_part[:-1]);`? Or is `F0` more a time-delayed control input, that is more frequently recomputed? Is there any randomness involved?